# debugging a Nodejs application listening on a port

Tags: node.js, debugging

I wanted to catch the request variable coming to the http server in nodejs debugger session within nodeclipse for the below Hello world code. I can debug the code using

node --debug-brk Helloworld.js

then starting the eclipse instance, by following [this link](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger) and the code will break at the below point

[image: Break at first line]

Now I put a breakpoint in line 14(console.log line), so that the http server listens on 8000 port. It reaches there.

[image: entering the line after httpserver]

Now i fire a request using soapui to http://127.0.0.1:8000, for me to capture the line in the debugger session, in which it will be caught/http request will be executed.

[image: soapui with request and url]

This is where I need a hint/guidance. I would like to see the request variable(populated with { samplerequest} in this case) in the debugger session. How do I do this?

Comment: Write console.log for samplerequest. it is simplest.

Comment: I wanted to capture that in the debugger session, use step into, step over commands, that way the variable will be shown in the variables section in debugger

Comment: I got this caught in the debugger... Thanks anyways :)